# gcsfuse on datalab vm machine. Error: fusermount: fuse device not found, try 'modprobe fuse' first

Tags: google-cloud-datalab, gcsfuse

I have installed gcsfuse on a datalab machine.
Created a target machine and used chmod to allow writing permission to all
calling:

```
!gcsfuse --foreground --debug_fuse archs4 /content/datalab/mount/
```

I am getting the following error:

```
Opening bucket...
Mounting file system...
mountWithArgs: mountWithConn: Mount: mount: running fusermount: exit status 1

stderr:
fusermount: fuse device not found, try 'modprobe fuse' first
```

any idea what might solve that issue?
(I am using: gcsfuse version 0.23.0 (Go version go1.9))

Thanks a lot,
Eila

Comment: For those who are running gscfuse in Cloud Run here is another answer https://serverfault.com/a/1098561/450511

Answer (score 4):

For any FUSE file system to work in a Docker container, you'll need to run the container in privileged mode. If you don't want to do this, at least you'll need these flags set when starting the container:

```
--security-opt apparmor:unconfined --cap-add mknod --cap-add sys_admin --device=/dev/<fuse_device> -v /mnt/<mnt_point>:/mnt/<mnt_point>:shared
```

Where `fuse_device` is the name of the FUSE drive you're using (for example gcsfuse), and `mnt_point` is the path you're mounting it at.

Keep in mind that Datalab doesn't run in privileged more or use these flags by default, so if you're running Datalab using the CLI tool (`datalab create` command), this won't work.

Comment: Thank you for your response. i have edited the startup script that is available on the datalab vm:

Comment: Thanks. I have edited the startup script that is available on the datalab compute engine settings to be:   docker run --rm --cap-add SYS_ADMIN -v "${MOUNT_DIR}/content:/content" --privileged --entrypoint "/bin/bash" gcr.io/cloud-datalab/datalab:latest gcloud source repos clone datalab-notebooks /content/datalab/notebooks . Added: --cap-add SYS_ADMIN and --privileged . should that be enough? I am starting the datalab, installing gcsfuse, creating a folder with write access to all and will run gcsfuse bucket folder . will that be enough or should i add the parameters in your response? thanks

Comment: and i wish to mount a bucket, is it possible to use the -v option for that:        -v /mnt/<mnt_point>:/mnt/<mnt_point>:shared

Comment: I think you still need to add the `mknod` capability. As for the `-v` flag, you use that to bind a mount point, and you'll mount the bucket from inside the container. You might need to make the volume shared first.