# Run AWS mount-s3 cli tool as a non-root Docker container and/or Kubernetes pod

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, kubernetes, amazon-s3, fuse

I am able to use [mountpoint-s3](https://github.com/awslabs/mountpoint-s3) in a Docker container that runs as `--privileged` on my machine, or even without --privileged, but with `--cap-add SYS_ADMIN --device /dev/fuse` docker command line options as it suggests [here](https://github.com/s3fs-fuse/s3fs-fuse/issues/647).

Is it possible to do it for a Kubernetes pod without extra admin capabilities? For security reasons, pods in our K8s cluster should not have admin access.

Comment: In general you shouldn't be able to mount(8) things into a container; this can potentially provide a path to escape the container or compromise the system.  Can you directly use the AWS SDK with its S3 client in your code?

Comment: I think [Is it possible to run gcsfuse without privileged mode inside GCP kubernetes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57525238/is-it-possible-to-run-gcsfuse-without-privileged-mode-inside-gcp-kubernetes) asks fundamentally the same question and seems to say that you need `CAP_SYS_ADMIN` to run FUSE.

Comment: Yes David. I could use the AWS S3 SDK in my Java app to download a file from S3 bucket to a persistent volume mounted to my pod, but I thought mounting the S3 directly could make life much easier.

Comment: Do you even need the persistent volume, though?  Or can you call S3, retrieve content into your process, and work on it directly without needing it as a file _per se_?

Comment: There's a big ~30GB data file kept in a S3 bucket, and an in-house-ish library needs to have access to it as a file (read only). For sure not all of it is loaded into memory at once. I'm not sure how it loads data chunks into memory or if it does at all.